# Adding + before result

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, parse-url

I want to add + in result so it appear as "+alrajhi12245"

```
$url = http://mydomain.com/alrajhi12245/invoice;
$parse = parse_url($url);
                $explode = explode('/', $parse['path']);
                $md = $explode[1];
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

```
$md = '+' . trim($explode[1]);
```

Comment: it shows a space between + and alrajhi12245 as"+ alrajhi12245"
, i need it without any spaces